# Compare two columns in excel and delete the duplicate row

Tags: excel, vba

I have below data in two columns in excel:

```
AB  CD

EF  GH

CD  AB

GH  EF
```

If the values in column1 matches any cell in column2, the row should be deleted. Starting from cell A1, the duplicate value is found in B3 so 3rd row is deleted. Moving on to A2, the duplicate value is found in B4 so 4th row is deleted.

Output should be

```
AB  CD

EF  GH
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to highlight duplicates but in my case every entry is duplicate so can't highlight and delete.

Comment: Your output and explanation do not match, form your explanation the output would be nil

Comment: Why can't you highlight and delete - your comment says it highlights the duplicates correctly which in this case is all of them, but I can't see how that stops you from deleting all of them?  If it's a case of it shouldn't be highlighting them all then you need to change your parameters for what constitutes a duplicate.

Comment: You say `If the values in column1 matches any cell in column2, the row should be deleted` yet in your example, the output includes `AB CD` even though `CD` is in column 22 (you said *any* cell)...  same for the the other example output.  You should probably re-think your explanation.

Comment: May be I was not able to express my problem, I have edited the explanation for easier understanding.

Comment: I made a clarification edit to the OP's question. Hopefully the clarification is correct and helps show why his output actually make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim firstCell as Range
Dim secondCell as Range

For Each firstCell in Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
    For Each secondCell in Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:B"))
        If firstCell.Value = secondCell.Value Then
            secondCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that when I've run into these scenarios, I've always ended up kicking myself for deleting data. I always advocate TESTING data more thoroughly before I just decide to terminate something. So, even though I think the VBA approach is elegant, I would go for an equation approach first, and give myself some easy flags for a mass-deletion. Equations below, and in picture.

[image: Illustration of how testing data would allow sort/filter action]

Column C testing if this is the first occurrence of data:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROW(A2)<MATCH(A2,B:B,0),"First","Duplc"),"First")
```

Column D, testing if this is the first occurrence of a data:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROW(B2)<MATCH(B2,A:A,0),"First","Duplc"),"First")
```

Column E, testing for First/First, Duplicate/Duplicate, or new single first occurances of data:

```
=IF(AND(C2="First",D2="First"),"Keep",IF(AND(C2="Duplc",D2="Duplc"),"Delete","Review"))
```

Any time I would see a "Review" cell, I'd test to make sure that I'm not deleting a valuable data point. Your data may be more simple than what I'm doing here, but I've regretted the ultra-powerful mass deletion.